# Querying a parquet file at a remote URL in DuckDB using R

Tags: r, duckdb

How can I run a query on a parquet file at a URL on the internet in DuckDB?

I'm running:

```r
library("DBI")
con = dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
sql <- r"(SELECT * FROM read_parquet('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinL/iris_parquet/main/iris.parquet'))
dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  duckdb_prepare_R: Failed to prepare query SELECT * FROM read_parquet('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinL/iris_parquet/main/iris.parquet')
Error: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinL/iris_parquet/main/iris.parquet"
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is correct, but you need to install the `httpfs` extension like so prior to running the query against the remote parquet file:

```
library("DBI")
con = dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), ":memory:")
sql <- "INSTALL httpfs; LOAD httpfs;"
dbExecute(con, sql)

sql <- r"(SELECT * FROM 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinL/iris_parquet/main/iris.parquet')"
dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```